# How do I block special characters in an input with Angular Material matInput

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I block special characters in

```
input matInput
```

I tried to do it this way, but it's not working:

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="data" placeholder="data" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" value="" maxlength="7">
```

Does anyone have any ideas or advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pattern` doesn't restrict the field to only typing what matches the pattern, it just decides if the input entered is valid or not. So you can make a validator and infor the user when an input is not valid. But if you want to completely restrict the user from typing something this is one option:

```
<input keypress="return String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g) === null">
```

**DEMO: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19jjvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**